# Checking for an open port AND if we can see any data from the service

Tags: ruby

I have a method that shows whether or not a port is opened or closed. However, application-layer firewalls will show ports as opened and actually restrict traffic if it's not a permitted protocol or service.

Here's the method I'm dealing with:

```
def is_port_open?(ip, port)
  begin
    Timeout.timeout(5) do
      begin
        s = TCPSocket.new(ip, port)
      rescue StandardError
        return false
      end
      s.close
      return true
    rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED, Errno::EHOSTUNREACH
      return false
    end
  rescue Timeout::Error
  end
  false
end
```

What's a good way to basically not only see if the port is opened, but try to send data to get something back before concluding it's opened? Alternatively, I guess I could just call nmap or call `curl` to run a GET request across the port (I'm only testing for HTTPS, for now at least).